# Recover password and login when using emails with concatenated words

Tags: python, algorithm, email, authentication

I have an app where multiple users are creating accounts concatenating the app name. This will create issues with the login and recover pass if the user forget what he added after the plus sign (+). Most likely, email not registered or account not found.

I am thinking about using this snippet, that will remove always everything between + and @, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to handle with this situation.

```
text = 'johndeere+company@example.com'
sep = '+'
at = '@'
first= text.split(sep, 1)[0]
second= text.split(at, 1)[1]

print first+at+second
```

Comment: Doesn't it depend on how you restrict the user name and app name? Let's say if you restrict that "@" and "+" is not allowed in user name and app name, then it is OK.

Comment: Why are you doing this at all?  Isn't the burden on the user to remember their login name?

Comment: @Sraw I don't think that restrict the use of + is good, since it's a valid character for the email specification.

Comment: @anvd So that means your solution is bad:( You shouldn't use "+" as the concatenating sign because it can appear in user's name. Why not choose another one?

Comment: @Sraw I think there is a misunderstanding. I am not using "+", the users are. The text is just a demo from the input of users.

Comment: @JohnGordon I agree, however for a small user base turn each account in a recoverable one, is relevant in my perspective.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. "+" is a valid character in an e-mail address. If your users haven't registered the e-mail address or forgot it, isn't that their problem? You can help mitigate against the former by having your app send them a confirmation email to verify their e-mail address by making them click a link in the e-mail before letting them complete the registration, which is something a lot of services do. Not much you can do to help them if they forgot the e-mail, though.

Comment: @ag415 The problem is that you can register `your_email+company_no_spam@gmail.com` and two weeks later you can't make the login or recover the account because you only remember `your_email@gmail.com`

Comment: Ok. Isn't that the user's fault for not remembering their e-mail, though? I mean, you could implement something where you can let the user do a partial search for their e-mail address, but then that creates a major vulnerability in your system that lets any random person search for registered e-mails